# extract objects that did not pass validations and show them in notifications

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

**Intro:** In short, this action let's you invite more users by mail, there is a field where you put your emails and on submit they all get emails with invitation by mail.

there is a method in the model that validates the email on project_invitation create so, inserting an invalid email type *(like: eee@em, fff.com, bbb@.com)*, pinv will not be saved and logger.error will be raised..

**The problem:** How do I extract all the emails that did not pass the validation and display them in a notice, something like "*Invtations sent, except eee@em, fff.com, bbb@.com, emails not valid"*.

Thank you, if any other info is needed, please let me know.

```
  def invite_users
    emails = params[:project_invitation][:emails]
    role = current_user.has_role?(:admin, @project) ? :admin : :default

    emails.to_s.split(',').each do |email|
      pinv = ProjectInvitation.new(params[:project_invitation], as: role)
      pinv.sender = current_user
      pinv.recipient_email = email
      pinv.recipient = nil
      pinv.project = @project

      if pinv.save
        ProjectMailer.delay.invitation(pinv)
      else
        logger.error("Failed to save project inv: #{pinv.errors.full_messages.join("\n")}")
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Capture the emails within your block, above your `logger.error`:

```
  invalid_emails = []

  if pinv.save
    ProjectMailer.delay.invitation(pinv)
  else
    invalid_emails << email
    logger.error("Failed to save project inv: #{pinv.errors.full_messages.join("\n")}")
  end

  if invalid_emails.any?
    flash[:notice] = "Invalid emails: #{invalid_emails.join(', ')}"
  end
```

The whole code:

```
  def invite_users
    emails = params[:project_invitation][:emails]
    role = current_user.has_role?(:admin, @project) ? :admin : :default

    invalid_emails = []

    emails.to_s.split(',').each do |email|
      pinv = ProjectInvitation.new(params[:project_invitation], as: role)
      pinv.sender = current_user
      pinv.recipient_email = email
      pinv.recipient = nil
      pinv.project = @project

      if pinv.save
        ProjectMailer.delay.invitation(pinv)
      else
        invalid_emails << email
        logger.error("Failed to save project inv: #{pinv.errors.full_messages.join("\n")}")
      end
    end

    if invalid_emails.any?
      flash[:notice] = "Invalid emails: #{invalid_emails.join(', ')}"
    end
  end
```